# Show a modal only once per time the user is on the site

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, cookies, bootstrap-4

I want to show a message to the user when opens the site and this code is not done until next enter to the site

this is my function that popup the modal

```
//do this if first visit of user 
$("#questionmodal").modal('show')
```

anyone know what I should do?

there is the welcome modal i want to show to user in first visit of him.
if user referesh the page or go to another page of site this modal should not be shown.

Comment: For the stuff that should happen only once you should use `setTimeout` instead. If you provide full code example (together with HTML) I can check what is wrong with it

Comment: hi @OleksandrSakun setTimeout work if i refresh the page or go to another page of site. i want to do this action in first visit of user

Comment: Try this approach:

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
   setTimeout(function () {
        $("#questionmodal").modal('show')
    }, 0);
})

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want the modal to only be shown once, when the user first comes to your website.

To achieve that, you need to store something on the user's web browser that marks that the user has already seen the popup.

There are multiple ways to do this. You can:

- use the [localStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

  - Storing that the modal has been shown (e.g in your code for when the modal closes) can be done using something like: `localStorage.setItem("modalshown", "1")`
  - Checking if the user has been shown the modal already (in an if statement before showing your modal) can be done with `localStorage.getItem("modalshown") == "1"`
- store the data in a [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/document/cookie), though be careful as those are being phased out